# Отслеживание нажатия на ссылку внутри textView, по нажатию на которую нужно сделать переход на другое активити

Tags: java, android, textview

Отслеживание нажатия на ссылку внутри textView, по нажатию на которую нужно сделать переход на другое активити.
Опишу подробнее, необходимо чтобы при нажатии на текст в textView, который помечен как ссылка в HTML разметке, перекидывало на другую активити и при этом на нее данные сбрасывало через putExtra

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Переход на другую активность можно сделать так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("link", stringlink);
startActivity(intent);
```

А в textView отловить клик не составит труда:

```
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

При условии что у вас там `html`. Вот например есть [библиотека](https://github.com/bluecabin/Textoo) которая делает решение вашей задачи проще. Чаще всего в textView ложат например номер телефона или адрес. А если делать клик на все textView то тогда можно сделать так:

```
TextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }

                });
```

Либо второй вариант - сделать выбор текста в textView, чтобы можно было выбрать определенное слово.